# jQuery UI - a method to close modal dialog that works more than once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog. I want to close it by clicking outside the dialog window.

There are many answers here and on Google that suggest to do this in the jQuery dialog function:

```
open: function(event,ui) {
                    $('.ui-widget-overlay').on('click', function(event,ui) {
                        alert("closing");        
                        $("#dialog-message").dialog("close");
                    });
                }
```

However, this for me works only once. If I am opening a dialog again, my alert goes off, but the dialog is not closing anymore.

I was able to workaround the issue by putting this in the beginning of the script, which closes all dialogs:

```
$('body').on('click','.ui-widget-overlay', function() {
    $('.ui-dialog').filter(function () {
    return $(this).css("display") === "block";
    }).find('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
    });
```

However, I want to get to the bottom of this and understand why everyone's answer seems to work for them, but does not work for me. I've seen examples in jsFiddle that work just fine, seemingly executing absolutely the same code.

SOLUTION:

My mistake was in thinking that when I do dialog("close") I destroy the dialog and then have to create a new one. Of course, in realty dialog("close") only hides the dialog. Therefore, I kept adding divs with the same id to the DOM. This obviously created problems.

Solution was to add the div once, create the dialog function once, make autoOpen: false and then just invoke the dialog whenever I needed it with the dialog("open") function. The contents of the dialog window are easily modifiable by modifying the contents of the dialog div as usual, using, say html().

Comment: Can you provide more context as to how you are initializing the dialogs and how many of them there are?

Comment: Hey Taplar, added the solution to the question. You were right in suspecting initialization as a possible cause for problems.